# How to automate the retrival of files based on datestamp

Tags: automation, pentaho

Im new to the pentaho suite and its automation functionality. i have files that come in on a daily basis and two columns need to be put in place. I have figured out how to add the columns but now i am stuck on the automation side of things. The filename is constant but it has a datestamp at the end. EG: LEAVER_REPORT_NEW_20110623.csv. The file will always be in the same directory. How do i go about using Pentaho data integration to solve this issue? ive tried get files but that doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a variable in a previous transform which contains 20110623 (easy with a get system info step to get the date, and then a select values step to format to string, then a set variables step)

then change the filename of the textfile input to use:

LEAVER_REPORT_NEW_${variablename}.csv

Comment: I tried that but it seems that you cant use a the set variable at the transformation level, it can only be used at job level

Comment: you can use it in a previous transformation, and use a job to wrap the two transformations.  Is there any reason why you can't use a job?